# こんなに汚いのに、それでも掃除したつもりですか。

Tags: meaning

> こんなに汚いのに、それでも掃除したつもりですか。

Does this mean :

1 - this is so dirty, do you intend to clean it?

or

2 - this is so dirty, did you think it was clean?

Comment: Duplicate of so many Q&A's here. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is correct (the latter is close, but still incorrect).

It should be: *It's so dirty, but you still think you cleaned it?*

I think you get the meaning of the first half, so I'll skip it.

それでも means *still, yet,* or *nevertheless*.

Ex:

- たくさん寝たのだが、**それでも**まだ眠い。
- *I slept a lot, but I'm **still** sleepy.*

つもり is *intention,* or *thought*. Here in this case, it's latter.

Ex:

- 今日は早く寝る**つもり**だ。
- *I'm **intending** to go to bed early today.*

---

- 仕事を全てやった**つもり**になっていたが、まだ残っていた。
- *I **thought** I had done all my work, but there was still more.*

So, conclusion:

- こんなに汚いのに、**それでも**掃除した**つもり**ですか。
- *It's so dirty, but you **still think** you cleaned it?*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So would it apply to this sentence also:

あなたはそれでもプロつもりですか。プロならきちんと仕事をしてください

"you STILL THINK your a pro, is your a pro, then work properly?"

amrite?

Comment: @fynxgloire Yes. Except your typo. あなたはそれでもプロ**の**つもりですか。プロならきちんと仕事をしてください - *You **still think** you're a pro(fessional)? if you're a pro(fessional), then do your work/job properly*